# Is there a way to update critical vulnerabilities in dependencies only with Renovate on Gitlab

Tags: security, gitlab, dependencies, renovate

we are thinking of using Renovate on Gitlab and havn't found anything on updating critical vulnerabilities dependencies only. We saw that it does distinguish between `mayor` and `minor` for example.

I found something in the Docs that it's possible on Github but nothing mentioned on Gitlab.

If there's no direct solution I'd also be interested with a "hacky" workaround.

Thank you

Comment: how to recognize an udpate with critical vulnerabilites ? You could have a packageRule with type you want: https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#matchupdatetypes